# Angular 2 - Router reloading component

Tags: angular

I am having problems with what looks to be the Angular router reloading the component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and causing undesired results. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/yRCzbsxE0ftzqrDeRT69?p=preview

Edit: How can I change it so the variable isn't reinitialized when alternating between link 'one' and 'two'

Comment: Please, edit the question and describe the undesired results you are seeing, where you are seeing them, and why they are undesirable.

Comment: Explain your problem, there are lot's of undesired facts around the world, one would be Donald Trump.

Answer (score 0):

this result is the correct according to your code.

at the first load

```
constructor() {
   this.fromParent = 'default'
}
```

the **fromParent** is set to default and the cousin component is initialized.

```
Click1

Click2
```

lets follow this scenario and see how does angular react to it:
click1 => angular route to /one, but parent component is already there, so no need to reloaded again, so it act normally at the first click.

click2 => angular route to /two, the route changed so angular reload the parent component, so its reload all your application and reset all variable to **default**

> when routing to some component, angular initialize this component, and in your case, your parent component is reInitialized again, which means reInitialize the cousin component.